# Conky problem - it's just a black window with text

Tags: conky

I've installed Conky on my computer following [these steps on noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/06/install-conky-lua-in-ubuntulinux.html). But all I got is a little black screen in the left of my desktop :/ please can someone help or show me how to remove Conky from my computer to try something else.

This is my desktop with the problem on it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how conky works by default - it just displays the raw data.

You'll need to apply a skin to make it look more appealing; you can find some on [this site](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/?q=conky) along with a nice walkthrough of configuration [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-Conky).

Comment: man you are awsome thank you so much dude you're the best (y)  that totaly solved my problem